# Calculating totals from 3 overlapping sets.

Tags: statistics

I was doing the followign GRE question:

*Of the students in Tanner's class, 8 wore a hat to school, 15 students wore gloves, and 10 wore scares. None of the students wore a scarf without gloves. Four students wore a hat, gloves, and a scarf. Half of the students who wore a hat also wore gloves. How many students are in Tanner's class?*

The answer to this (which I did end up getting later on) is 8+15+10-(10-4)-(4-4)-(2*4) = 19

However, I'm having some trouble relating this to the formula of overlapping sets, where N = A + B + C – (a + b + c + 2x) +p

In this case, N = 8+15+10 - (10+4+8) = 11, which is wrong.

Can someone show me where my thinking is flawed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with your formula of overlapping sets. You'll have to explain to us what each variable represents. It seems similar to the [Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), which states that the number of elements in the union of three sets $A,B,C$ is given by:
$$
|A \cup B \cup C| = (|A| + |B| + |C|) - (|A \cap B| + |A \cap C| + |B \cap C|) + |A \cap B \cap C|
$$
In this case, we have:
$$
|H \cup G \cup S| = (8 + 15 + 10) - (4 + 4 + 10) + 4 = 19
$$
Alternatively, notice that the statement: "None of the students wore a scarf without gloves." tells us that $S \subseteq G$. Hence, we have:
$$
|H \cup G \cup S| = |H \cup G| = |H| + |G| - |H \cap G| = 8 + 15 - 4 = 19
$$